# Different domain for different magento store view

Tags: store-view, multidomain, 301-redirect

I have a Magento installation in m.theseolounge.co.uk with English (default) and German store views. When the user select the German site I want to have the German view to display the URL marsdenweighing.de. I have change the Base URL in Magento, added a parked domain on my host and pointed the domain to my host. IN addition to this I have added the code below in the .htaccess file above the Rewrite On:

```
SetEnvIf Host www\.m\.theseolounge\.co\.uk MAGE_RUN_CODE=default
SetEnvIf Host www\.m\.theseolounge\.co\.uk MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^m\.theseolounge\.co\.uk MAGE_RUN_CODE=default
SetEnvIf Host ^m\.theseolounge\.co\.uk MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host www\.marsdenweighing\.de MAGE_RUN_CODE=german
SetEnvIf Host www\.marsdenweighing\.de MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
SetEnvIf Host ^marsdenweighing\.de MAGE_RUN_CODE=german
SetEnvIf Host ^marsdenweighing\.de MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
```

Still no luck If I select from http://m.theseolounge.co.uk the German store, I get redirected to http://marsdenweighing.de/german/?SID=34djak9idkc7jq98c63g2mg5b6&___from_store=default

Why is the /german/ appended to the URL and why "SID=34djak....?
Any pointer?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the `/german` part of the url is the store code. This can be configured in the admin section under `System->Config->General->Web->Url Options`. After setting `Add Store Code to Url` to No you should no longer get these added.

Secondly the `SID` is the session id. Again this can be configured to show/not show via the admin section. Under `System->Config->General->Web->Session validation settings` there is the option for `Use SID in frontend`